# How to read specific XML attributes dynamically in PowerShell from a different xml nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this following XML that I need to read the attributes dynamically however I am stuck in finding the correct way to do it in PS:

```
<DataGroups>
  <Category1 Identifier="Project789">
  <Category2 Identifier="Project234">
  <SimpleCategory56 Identifier="Project56">
  ......
</DataGroups>
```

I have tried the following till now which works however how do I do this dynamically??

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $Path)
$test = $xml.DataGroups.Category1.Identifier
```

I have also tried doing something this:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $Path)
Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//Category1/@Identifier"
```

but then I am getting somwthing cryptic like the following:

```
Node       Path        Pattern
----       ----        -------
Identifier InputStream //Category1/@Identifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. You had to simply try this in the `Select-Xml`:

```
$xml = [xml](get-content $Path)
(Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//./@Identifier").Node.Value
```

Please try and let me know. It should return

```
Project789
Project234
Project56
```